# Showing that $\text{Gal}(\Omega^{X^n -a}_K/K(\zeta_n))$ is Abelian, for char$(K) = 0$ and $0 \not = a \in K$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $K$ be a field and $L = \Omega^{X^n -a}_K$ be the splitting field of $X^n-a$. I have already proven that $\zeta_n$ a primitive $n$-th root of unity is in $L$, hence the above question makes sense.

Comment: I suppose $\;\zeta_n:=e^{2\pi i/n}\;$, but how do proving it is a primitive $\;n\,-$th root of unity helps you to prove what you want to prove? Perhaps you should begin by pointing out what the roots of $\;X^n-a\in K[X]\;$ are and thus what its splitting field is?

Comment: @DonAntonio nobody said $K = \Bbb Q$; knowing that $\zeta_n \in L$ makes the notation $\text{Gal}(\Omega^{X^n -a}_K/K(\zeta_n))$ well-defined.

Comment: Does this not follow from the fact that any $K(\zeta_n)$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ is uniquely determines by the exponent $k$ (an integer defined modulo $n$) such that $\sigma(a)=\zeta_n^ka$? Denoting that automorphism by $\sigma_k$ we see that $\sigma_k\circ\sigma_\ell=\sigma_{k+\ell}$, addition modulo $n$. Therefore the Galois group. is isomorphic to a subgroup of the additive group $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. Whether all choices of $k$ occur depends on $a$.